Hot Reload/Hot Deployment in Tomcat using VS Code
I'm trying to enable hot reload for tomcat using vs code. Since "tomcat for java" extension has been deprecated which makes me use "community server connectors" extension in vs code, i can't seem to enable hot reload without having to manually enter "mvn clean package" in the terminal and then redeploy it. Is there a way to auto-update the changes made to the index.jsp file?
I tried everything but can't seem to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance!

The issue is undefined. What do you mean "tomcat for java"?

Tomcat for java extension is what i meant. It has been deprecated in visual studio code

Tomcat is a standalone server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35113062/573032

i'm sorry, it should be hot reload for maven instead, not tomcat. Instead of typing "mvn clean package" in terminal, it should be an automatic hot reload. Any ideas of how to do this?

It is unclear what you asking, actually "mvn clean package" is not doing hot reload. It removes classes in the output folder, and then recompiled it again, the final war file is created in the "target" folder. Then you deploy the war file to the tomcat, then what is happening with it you can read in the previous comment's linked answer.

yes exactly. The final war file is created in the target folder and i deploy the war file to my server and ONLY THEN i can view the changes made. Isn't there a way to make it automatically update the war file to the tomcat so i don't have to redeploy it to tomcat every single time i want to view the changes? This was my question from the beginning and thank you for replying and helping me with this issue!

Hello, you can try to do this through the extension community server connectors or configure tomcat. Configure the server.xml file for Tomcat. Modify the Context element under the Host element in the file. Add <Context docBase="/yourpath" path="/yourapp" reloadable="true". Then set autoDeploy="true" to allow automatic deployment. Save and restart after modification. See if that results can be achieved.

The host element was set to this from the beginning:

I even tried adding this to my server.xml:

I restarted it and it still doesn't hot reload when i make changes to the index.jsp file. Any ideas of how to fix that?

Maybe try taking a look at the DCEVM. It is allowed to be redefined at runtime without limitations. You can add/remove fields and methods at runtime.

Okay after many trials and errors i finally managed to fix it somehow :D
SOLUTION:
When adding a deployment, chose "Exploded" and not "File". This should solve it as it did to me!

I'm glad to hear that you've found a good way to solve your problem. You can edit it into an answer and mark it up if you want, I guess it's very beneficial for members who have similar questions.

SOLVED!
SOLUTION: When adding a deployment, chose "Exploded" and not "File". This should solve it as it did to me!
